# Service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password, domainname);

Tags: c#, exchange-server

Every time I try to run this I get this error:

> "Service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password,
>   domainname);"

Nothing online seems to help.

Note: I'm trying to read emails from my inbox.
Any and all help is welcome.
Cheers

I've tried to change this email and the line above it nothing works.

```
ExchangeService exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
            exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials("(myEmailAddress)", "(myEmailPassword)", "(gmail.com is the correct domain right?)");
            exchange.AutodiscoverUrl("(myEmailAddress)");

            if(exchange != null)
            {
                FindItemsResults<Item> result = exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(100));

                foreach(Item item in result)
                {
                    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id);

                    String body = message.Body.Text;
                    String from = message.From.Id.ToString();
                    String subject = message.Subject.ToString();
                }
            }
```

It should just read my emails.
The data I want to get is as follows:
From address
Emails subject
Email body

Comment: ExchangeService exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
            exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials("gmtower1@gmail.com", "GabeIsGreat", "gmail.com");
            exchange.AutodiscoverUrl("gmtower1@gmail.com");

Comment: This is the error-ed code block. Sorry

Comment: Re edit this it's hard to read please.

Comment: Also have you looked at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: In this context, domain name is referring to an active directory domain, not a web domain. Also, the credentials are for an exchange mailbox, not google. I don't think you can use EWS to connect to non-exchange email servers.